# Entity Framework Many to Many List Table Association

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following classes (I am only showing the properties that matter):

```
public class TypeLocation
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Country {get; set;}
    public string State {get; set;}
    public string County {get; set;}
    public string City {get; set;}

    public List<Offer> Offers {get; set; }
    public TypeLocation()
    {
        this.Offers = new List<Offer>();
    }
}

public class Offer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TypeLocation> LocationsToPublish { get; set; }
}
```

This creates the following in the database:

[image: Database Schema]

**My Question/Problem**

The `TypeLocations` table is prepopulated with a static list of country/state/county/city records, one or many of them can be associated with the Offer in `LocationsToPublish` property.  When I try to add a location, using the following code, Entity Framework adds a NEW record in the `TypeLocation` table and then makes the association by adding a record in the `OfferTypeLocations` table.

```
    public static bool AddPublishLocation(int id, List<TypeLocation> locations)
    {
        try
        {
            using (AppDbContext db = new AppDbContext())
            {
                Offer Offer = db.Offers
                    .Include("LocationsToPublish")
                    .Where(u => u.Id == id)
                    .FirstOrDefault<Offer>();

                //Add new locations
                foreach (TypeLocation loc in locations)
                {
                    Offer.LocationsToPublish.Add(loc);
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I don't want a new record added to the `TypeLocations` table, just a relational record creating an association in the `OfferTypeLocations` table. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

**Solution**

Thanks to @Mick who answered below, I have found the solution.

```
    public static bool AddPublishLocation(int id, List<TypeLocation> locations)
    {
        try
        {
            using (AppDbContext db = new AppDbContext())
            {
                Offer Offer = db.Offers
                    .Include("LocationsToPublish")
                    .Where(u => u.Id == id)
                    .FirstOrDefault<Offer>();

                //Add new locations
                foreach (TypeLocation loc in locations)
                {
                    //SOLUTION
                    TypeLocation ExistingLoc = db.AppLocations.Where(l => l.Id == loc.Id).FirstOrDefault<TypeLocation>();

                    Offer.LocationsToPublish.Add(loc);
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

What happens is, using the existing AppDbContext, I retrieve an existing record from the TypeLocations table (identified here as `AppLocations`) and then Add it to the LocationsToPublish entity.

The key is that I was to use the current AppDbContext (wrapped with the Using() statement) for all the work.  Any data outside of this context is purely informational and is used to assist in the record lookups or creation that happen within the AppDbContext context.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: If you open profiler you'll see that this solution generates extra queries for each location added.  It will work, however it will be substantially slower than the solution below.

Comment: The List<TypeLocation> is actually generated from the data post off a web page so there isnt any context to pass in.  In actuality, we should not have too many TypeLocations passed in at any point in time, maybe 10-15 max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TypeLocations are being loaded from a different AppDbContext, they are deemed new entities in the AppDbContext you're constructing within your method.  To fix either:-

1. Assuming the locations were detatched them from the instance of the AppDbContext outside of your method, you can attach these entities to the new context.
   OR
2. Pass in the AppDbContext used to load the locations into your AddPublishLocation method.

I'd choose 2:-

```
public static bool AddPublishLocation(AppDbContext db, int id, List<TypeLocation> locations)
{
    try
    {
        Offer Offer = db.Offers
            .Include("LocationsToPublish")
            .Where(u => u.Id == id)
            .FirstOrDefault<Offer>();

        //Add new locations
        foreach (TypeLocation loc in locations)
        {
            Offer.LocationsToPublish.Add(loc);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how they are being loaded from a different AppDbContext.  Do you have more information about this?

Comment: I thought about your answer and found a solution!  Basically, I needed to retrieve existing TypeLocation records from the table matching the IDs of the locations I am trying to add.  I have updated my question.

Comment: Each time you instantiate a new AppDbContext that instance tracks all the entities that were loaded through the context, an entity that is not loaded through that instance of the AppDbContext is treated as a new entity when it is added to the context. Your original code clearly passes in the TypeLocations which must have been loaded elsewhere with a different instance of the AppDbContext.  In order for the entities to be treated as existing entities they need to be attached or loaded through the AppDbContext in your method, which is why your solution works

Comment: Updated my answer to try and be a little more succinct